# String object is not making it from the Controller to the Razor Component

Tags: json, blazor

I have a Controller that defines a number of Get methods.  The Razor Component is able to read all the Gets using `GetFromJsonAsync()` without any issue.  However, one of the Get methods returns a `string` object.  The Razor Component keeps blowing up when trying to read that `string`.

MyController.cs

```
[HttpGet("GetObject")]
public async Task<MyObject> GetObject(int? id)
{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    // ... do some work here and fill in obj
    return obj;
}

[HttpGet("GetString")]
public async Task<string> GetString(int? id)
{
    string retval = "";
    // ... do some work here and fill in retval 
    return retval;
}
```

MyComponent.razor

```
// this call works
MyObject myObj = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<string>("My/GetObject?id=15");

// this call throws a Json syntax error
string myString = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<string>("My/GetString?id=15");
```

I'm not sure why the system is able to read all my `object`s with the exception of the `string` object.  Has anyone else run into this issue with being unable to read `string`s from the Controller?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what is going on.  It appears that if your Controller is returning a `string` object, Blazor is assuming that you have already converted your data into a true Json string and will not attempt to serialize it into Json for you.  So I had to serialize it myself on the Controller side.   Then my Razor Component picked up the original string as intended.  Here is the solution:

```
[HttpGet("GetString")]
public async Task<string> GetString(int? id)
{
    string retval = "";
    // ... do some work here and fill in retval 
    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<string>(retval);
}
```